# Run Void From Form 1 Using Form 2

Tags: c#

I'am trying to execute a Void from Form2 and update Form1 i have tried adding it on button click and also on Form_Close, and also on Form1_Activated, Form1_Enter but still no progress

Here Is What I Have tried :( but no luck in making it work...

Form1.cs

```
public void LoadTable()
{
   //Code to Populate Datagridview
   string sql = "";
   SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(Global.Connection);
   SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand(sql, Connection);

   SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter();
   DA.SelectCommand = CMD;

   DataSet DS = new DataSet();
   DA.Fill(DS);

   ApplicantsGrid.DataSource = DS.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
private void Form1Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 Form2 = new Form2();
    Form2.showDialog();
}
```

Form2.cs

```
private void Form2Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Form1 Form1 = new Form1();
      Form1.LoadTable();
}
```

well this is the main problem of the program iam making :(

Comment: Its working correctly. `new` creates a *new* instance.

Comment: well problem is... the table won't repopulate i mean it wont repopulate the datagridview :(

Comment: Type `Form1.Show();` on the next line. Also, its not a good idea to name a variable the same as its class

Comment: lemme update my question to make things more clear

Comment: i don't know why people are downing this question :( i dont see anything wrong

Comment: You're question has been asked a million times before (see the related questions on the right for a list of a few), so your question does not show research effort. For the record, I didn't downvote.

Comment: thanks for not downvoting :) well i tried looking at other questions but didnt seem to get the right answer that is appropriate for my situation :( and one more thing.. i dont know how to call my problem so my searching for other questions might have given me wrong questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure, that you are doings something else you want.

You are calling the `LoadTable` on new instance of the `Form1`. What you probably want is to call it on the existing form, as suggested by Sayse.

You probably want to call it on an existing instance. You might achieve that like this, for example:

Form1 Button_Click code:

```
class Form1
{
    public static Form1 Instance {get; private set;}

    public Form1()
    {
        Instance = this;
        //InitializeComponents and what ever else.
    }

    public void LoadTable()
    {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

Form2 code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Form1.Instance != null) //must be careful about this.
    {
        Form1.Instance.LoadTable(); //like this you will call the method on the existing instance of the form.
    }
}
```

Comment: well the thing is that form1 is the first form... then i click button on form1 to show form2 in dialog mode and there is button on form2 that makes the datagridview on form1 refresh/update using a code inside form1... well lemme try your answer :)

Comment: Thanks For The Answer! It Worked Exactly As Needed :) sorry if my question is not that clear... i thought that my question already implied that iam using a currently open form :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        internal static Form1 ViewForm1; // Make other form run Public void from Form1

        public form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewForm1 = this;  //Add this
        }
        public void DoSomething()
        {
          //Code here...
        }
}   


 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            Form1.ViewForm1.ShowData(); // Call public void from form1
        }
    }
```

```html
     public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            internal static Form1 ViewForm1; // Make other form run Public void from Form1

            public form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                ViewForm1 = this;  //Add this
            }
            public void DoSomething()
            {
              //Code here...
            }
    } 
 

     public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public form2()
            {
                InitializeComponent();            
                Form1.ViewForm1.ShowData(); // Call public void from form1
            }
  }
```

Comment: Please explain why this code will answer the OP's question.  Just code snippets don't count as a full answer per the SO guidelines.